# How to get data from json array using names instead of index with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've been trying to get json data with jquery using names but without succeed, only works with object index, this is my code:

```
var json = [
   {
      "idiom":[
         {
            "nombre":"español",
            "id":1
         },
         {
            "nombre":"ingles",
            "id":2
         }
      ]
   }
];

console.log(json)
$.each( json[0], function( key, data ) {
$.each(data, function(index, indata) {
console.log(indata.nombre);
});
});

console.log('-------');
$.each( json.idiom, function( key, data ) {
$.each(data, function(index, indata) {
console.log(indata.nombre);
});
});
```

If I try to access with *json.idiom* isntead of *json[0]* the code doesn't work

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wm0de41h/

Comment: `json.idiom` would work if you had `json = { "idiom": [ ... ] }` but you don't...

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: I put it that way because I will add more arrays, not only "idiom" thats why the [ ] at the beginning, e.g. json =  [ {"idiom": [ ... ]}, {"age": [ ... ]}, {"city": [ ... ]} ]

Comment: You can have more than one key per object, you know? You don't need an array for `{ "idiom": [...], "age": [...], "city": [...] }` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having to access `json[0]` because it's an array with a single item in it. If you want to access `json.idiom` you'll need to restructure your object to:

```
var json = {
  "idioms":[
    {
       "nombre":"español",
       "id":1
    },
    {
       "nombre":"ingles",
       "id":2
    }
  ]
};
```

Notice how there are no square brackets around your `json` object now. (I also pluralized `idioms` since it's an array.

Finally, you don't need jquery to iterate this. You can use an [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```
json.idiom.forEach(function(idiom) {
    console.log(idiom.nombre);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my full json has three objects instead of only one, it's the same? This is my full json: https://jsfiddle.net/z7ab4t6t/

Comment: so you want also interes and estrado and not only nombre !!!  are you kidding us ???

Comment: I am asking because I don't know if it's possible, i'm still very new on this, I thought that could be the same for three objects with different data on each one.

Comment: @ElrosRomeo You need to learn more about how JSON objects work and how to traverse them in Javascript. We are not going to write your code for you.

Comment: I'm not asking you to write the code or I wrote something like that? That's why I put a fiddle with my code, I'm just asking for guidence to keep trying to fix my code.

Answer (score -3):

A JSON object is defined using curly braces `{}`, not brackets `[]`. Try removing the brackets, which would leave you with this:

```
var json = {
  "idiom":[
     {
        "nombre":"español",
        "id":1
     },
     {
        "nombre":"ingles",
        "id":2
     }
  ]
};
```

See the JavaScript object documentation at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).